# webpack css loader not work: no output css file

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I'm working on opensource project, right now i need to setup webpack for front end. i tried webpack config below, JS is works fine, but css isn't, no css output file. i dont why this happen, please help me.

below is my webpack config js file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const node_dir = __dirname + '/node_modules';

const sassLoaders = [
  'css-loader',
  'sass-loader?indentedSyntax=sass&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, './public/stylesheets/')
]

const config = {
    addVendor: function (name, path) {
        this.resolve.alias[name] = path;
        this.module.noParse.push(new RegExp('^' + name + '$'));
    },

    entry: {
        app: './public/javascripts/app.js',
    vendors: ['jquery','underscore']
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? './public/dist' : './public/dev'),
        filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '[name].[hash].js' : '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'public/dev'
    },

    module:{
        noParse: [],
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', sassLoaders.join('!'))
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader:'babel?presets[]=es2015'
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {},
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.scss'],
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("qor.css", {
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendors.bundle.js'),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery"
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          _: "underscore",
        })
    ]
};

config.addVendor('jquery', node_dir + '/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
config.addVendor('underscore', node_dir + '/underscore/underscore.js');

module.exports = config;
```

when i run `webpack -d --watch --progress --colors` there is no css file output. just js files.

[image]

here is my project folder

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Didn't you forget to require your stylesheet in js entry point using require:

```
// in your modules just require the stylesheet
// This has the side effect that a <style>-tag is added to the DOM.
require("./stylesheet.css");
```

If you want to generate a native css output file, check out [this guide from webpack documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html#separate-css-bundle).

Answer (score 1):

Just completing the @denysdovhan:

When using webpack 4+ you will need provide in the `package.json` the property `sideEffect`:

```
{
  "name": "your-project",
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

You can see the explanation here: [Link](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free)